# Multiple toString() Methods with Generics

Tags: java, generics, tostring

I have an object which will be stored in two different data structures.

I am using generics, and each structure has to print out the object in a different way. Is there a way to have multiple `toString()` methods that will invoke accordingly?

I can't create two different methods that return a string, as custom methods are not defined in the generic type, so you can't call them unless you cast it, which breaks the point behind generics.

Should I just create two different objects with different `toString()` methods for each data structure? Or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me that you hope how to call the multiple toString() method to get different String? How do you know that an object is stored in any data structure?

Comment: true - i think I need two different classes. no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the `toString()` of the different objects, but you should still be able to do this with generics in place.

I imagine your generic class has at least one instance of the generic type.  If that is the case, override your generic classes `toString()` to delegate to the generic type object instance.

If your generic class only has a single instance, you can do something like this:

```
class Holder<T> {
    private T instance;

    public Holder(T _instance) {
        instance = _instance;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return instance.toString();
    }
}
```

And if your class has multiple instances of the generic type (as with many `Collection`'s), you can delegate to each instance of the type.

```
class CollectionHolder<T> {
    private Collection<T> collection;

    public CollectionHolder(Collection<T> _collection) {
        collection= _collection;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(T t : collection) {
            builder.append(t); //same as builder.append(t.toString())
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: My object has only one generic type instance. But how would `instance.toString();` differ depending on who calls it? Where do I set how it will be print out?

Comment: Well, you would need to define the `toString()` method on your generic types.  When this is in place, it will call the `toString()` methods of the given type, and this will not require multiple `toString()`'s to be defined in your generic class.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call it on both you need to add it to your interface. It's entirely possible you don't want to use toString() for it, since toString() is supposed to be a human readable representation.

```
class Nay1 {

    String someCrazyMethod() { return "ugh"; }
}

class Nay2 {

    String someRandomMethod() { return "ook"; }
}
```

Well this sucks. You wouldn't want a Nay1 to ook, or a Nay2 to ugh. But you need something uniform!

interface NayInterface {

```
String nayRepresentation();
```

}

And your new classes:

```
class Nay1 implements NayInterface  {

    String someCrazyMethod() { return "ugh"; }

    public String nayRepresentation() { return someCrazyMethod(); }
}

class Nay2 implements NayInterface {

    String someRandomMethod() { return "ook"; }

    public String nayRepresentation() { return someRandomMethod(); }
}
```

Now no matter what, you can call `myNayInterface.nayRepresentation();` to get your string representation that matches the appropriate class without doing any casting.

```
class ActuallyDoesSomething<T extends NayInterface> {

    String foo;

    public ActuallyDoesSomething(T t) {
        this.foo = t.nayRepresentation();
    }

    public String foo() { return foo; }

}
```

Obviously if you want to use toString() instead of nayRepresentation, you can do that. But this will allow you to not have to consume toString and keep that instead for debugging purposes.

Comment: So you're saying just create two different objects, which are the exact same copy and just change the toString() in each?

Comment: That's one way to do it. It depends on what it's for; I wouldn't recommend using toString() for something other than a human readable representation of the object.

Comment: Yes I want it for that. I need it for a human readable representation.

Comment: Then yes toString is perfect.